# NoReverseMatch at/ Django

Tags: python, django, render

Помогите пожалуйста, пол дня убил, не могу понять, почему выдает ошибку:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'the_redhuman_is.views.new_worker' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []``
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Error during template rendering
In template /home/redhuman/redhuman_is/the_redhuman_is/templates/the_redhuman_is/base.html, error at line 7
Reverse for 'the_redhuman_is.views.new_worker' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Шаблон:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'the_redhuman_is.views.new_worker' %}">Собаки</a></p>
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'the_redhuman_is'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', views.base, name='base'),
url(r'^new-worker/$', views.new_worker, name='new-worker'),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
from .models import Worker
from .forms import WorkerForm

def base(request):
   return render(request, 'the_redhuman_is/base.html', {})

def new_worker(request):
   form = WorkerForm()
   return render(request, 'the_redhuman_is/new_worker.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Worker

class WorkerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = ('input_date', 'last_name', 'name', 'patronymic', 'passport_number', 'birth_date', 'mig_series', 'mig_number', 'm_date_of_issue', 'm_date_of_exp',)
```

Comment: С корее всего в шаблоне ошибка. С аргументами для функции.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url

> The first argument is a url() name.

Исправь имя вьюхи в шаблоне:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'new-worker' %}">Собаки</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправте шаблон на:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'the_redhuman_is.new_worker' %}">Собаки</a></p>
```

Так как, обращение к `name='new_worker'` через `app_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Я убрал переменную app_name и все сработало

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]